# Groovy closure - Parameter in JobDSL in Jenkins

Tags: groovy, closures, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to run the Jenkins jobdsl in loop. I get following error

ERROR: (CreateIncrementalJobs.groovy, line 15) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.parameters() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[      stringParam('BRANCH', 'dev'),       booleanParam('BUILD_APP', false), ...]]

I have a params.txt file where all parameters are mentioned for different jobs. I am running pipelineJOb creation in loop.

```
def params = new File(paramFilePath).text.readLines()
pipelineJob(JobName) {
   parameters {
       parameters(params)
   }
   definition {...
```

Content of params.txt

```
     stringParam('BRANCH', 'dev')
     booleanParam('BUILD_APP', false)
```

I tried giving only parameters(params) and also params. Still not working. It is expecting a closure i guess. Is there a way to convert the content of txt file into closure?